# In Chrome browser, Modal pop up pops up when clicking a button which is disabled

Tags: asp.net, ajax, google-chrome

I have a page which has a modal pop up which shows on clicking a link button. I have disabled the link button but on clicking the disabled link button also the modal pop up appears. It works fine in all other browsers except Chrome. How to prevent modal pop up from being shown when the link button(target control) is disabled?

The code is given below:

```
 <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
            CancelControlID="imgbtnCancel" DropShadow="true" PopupControlID="panelTenant"
            TargetControlID="lnkbtnTenant">
        </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="panelTenant" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none" Width="400px"
            runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="btnTest" Text="Test" runat="server"></asp:Button>
        </asp:Panel>
```

In page_load event of the code, I have checked a condition and disabled the link button when the condition fails.

```
if (ds.Tables[3].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lnkbtnTenant.Enabled = true;
                lnkbtnTenant.Text = "Click to view Tenant Details";               
            }
            else
            {
                lnkbtnTenant.Enabled = false;
                lnkbtnTenant.Text = "Tenant Details not available.";                
            }
```

---

**Edited** to include the generated-html, posted by OP in the comments:

This is the resulting HTML of the modal pop up:

```
<div id="ctl00_head_panelTenant" class="modalPopup" style="width:400px;display: none">
     <input type="submit" name="ctl00$head$btnTest" value="Test" id="ctl00_head_btnTest"/>
</div>
```

This is the resulting HTML of the disabled button:

```
<a id="ctl00_head_lnkbtnTenant" disabled="disabled" class="para1">Tenant Details not available.</a>
```

Comment: Please show us your code from the CodeBehind

Comment: Please show the resulting HTML as well.

Comment: I have pasted the mark up as well as the code. On clicking the link button which is disabled, the modal pop up shows up in Chrome browser.

Comment: @banup Great. But please show the resulting HTML as well.

Comment: resulting HTML:    
<div id="ctl00_head_panelTenant" class="modalPopup" style="width:400px;display: none"> 
  
      <input type="submit" name="ctl00$head$btnTest" value="Print" id="ctl00_head_btnPrintPreview" class="small" /> 
   <input type="submit" name="ctl00$head$btnTest" value="Test" id="ctl00_head_btnTest"/>          
</div>

Comment: @banupriya, where, in the generated html, is the link button? I ask because neither of the `submit` buttons you mentioned are disabled (at least not that I can see).

Comment: This is the resulting HTML of the button which is disabled    <a id="ctl00_head_lnkbtnTenant" disabled="disabled" class="para1">Tenant Details not available.</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like ASP.NET puts a disabled="disabled" attribute onto the anchor, which is not valid HTML. Chrome ignores this non-standard attribute, hence you can still click on the link.

Comment: Ok. Do you have any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm afraid we didn't come up with a proper solution, we chose not to emit an anchor at all and used a span instead.

Comment: If you are only using anchors with hrefs (and not click events), then you could use this little bit of jQuery to disable the anchors when there is a disabled="disabled" attribute: $('a[disabled=disabled]').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});